# Porting from Python 3 to the six library (dual python 2 and 3 support)

Tags: python, six

I have a python 3 project, and would like to add support for python 2. There is the `3to2` conversion utility, but its output is python 2. I want to support both 2 and 3. I know the `six` library supports this. But I'm wondering if there is a conversion tool or something like that which would convert from python 3 to using the `six` library (or, if there is some other not-totally-manual way to achieve this goal)?

Comment: There's not really anything good. Do it manually. And better to use [python-future](https://python-future.org) as the compat layer, because `six` is pretty crappy.

Comment: There are going to be limits; `six` can't fix raw syntax differences, so if you used any syntax features of Py3 that don't exist in Py2 even with `__future__` imports, you'd need to run at least some of the `3to2` fixers.

Comment: My recommendation is to do it manually. Find an editor that can do find and replace on many files at once, and go down [this](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html) list of differences between the languages. I've never had great luck with automated tools unless I wrote them ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks from the suggestions in the comments, I looked into [python-future](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future) and found that it provides a conversion tool from python 3 to python2/3 (with the supporting [python-future](https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future) library) called [pasteurize](https://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html#pasteurize-py3-to-py2-3). It also provides a similar tool to convert from python 2 to python2/3 called [futurize](https://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html#futurize-py2-to-py2-3).

I tested [pasteurize](https://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html#pasteurize-py3-to-py2-3), and it worked for my project. Some cleanup may be helpful after running either of these tools, but they certainly seem to provide a good first cut at the problem.